# Bottom border on fpdf17 is transparant

Tags: php, web, export, fpdf

i'm newbie..

this is my code to create the last row from my table:

```
$pdf->Cell(120,8,"Total Keseluruhan",1,0,'C',true);
$pdf->Cell(40,8,$sum_jumlah." items",1,0,'L',true);
$pdf->Cell(40,8,$print_sum_total_harga,1,1,'C',true);
```

my question:
**why bottom border in the last row transparant? can i change it?**

you can see this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofcyT.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The line is not transparent but its a render issue. Try different zoom levels and you will see that the linewidths are equal.